# List of CNN for Emotion/Sentiment recognition on images with performance on main datasets (IAPS, GAPED, EmoPics, NAPS)

Tags: cnn, image-classification, image-recognition, sentiment-analysis

There are more and more databases of pictures classified or rated with emotions.

For instance, I know of 4 databases (IAPS, GAPED, EmoPics, NAPS) rating pictures on 2 dimensions: Valance (positive vs negative) and Arousal.

There are also databases with pictures classified as representing various emotions (POFA,KDEF,NimStim). Categories are emotions like anger, sadness, awe,...

While I find many papers using pictures from these databases on humans to generate emotions, I was wondering if there were convolutional neural networks (CNN) that were trained to regress/classify emotions. So far I just know of EmoNet was created by researchers from the University of Colorado and Duke University.

Is there a paper, competition, or website that lists and/or compare various neural nets for this task ? Something similar to what we had with ILSVRC to compare the image classification algorithms.